# How to execute a CMD /C command with ( round bracket in the path name

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to execute a command like this:

```
CMD /C "C:\Users\Richard(R)D\abc.bat"
```

I get the error message:

```
'C:\Users\Richard' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

How can I execute the command that resides in a folder that uses round brackets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try escaping the parentheses with a circumflex ^

```
CMD /C "C:\Users\Richard^(R^)D\abc.bat"
```

Answer (score 4):

*Why?*

If you read the `cmd /?` output you will find

```
If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
used to process quote (") characters:

    1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
        on the command line are preserved:

        - no /S switch
        - exactly two quote characters
        - no special characters between the two quote characters,
          where special is one of: &<>()@^|
        - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
          two quote characters
        - the string between the two quote characters is the name
          of an executable file.

    2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
        a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
        remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
        any text after the last quote character.
```

This means that

```
cmd /c "C:\Users\Richard(R)D\abc.bat"
```

gets the quotes removed and the remaining command

```
cmd /c C:\Users\Richard(R)D\abc.bat
```

has a problem with the parenthesis.

*How?*

For this precise command, you can escape the parenthesis

```
cmd /c "C:\Users\Richard^(R^)D\abc.bat"
```

Or for a general solution you can include quotes for the file

```
cmd /c ""C:\Users\Richard(R)D\abc.bat""
```

and better (if executing from command line) also escape the first quote to avoid parser problems in quoted areas start/stop (not needed in this case)

```
cmd /c ^""C:\Users\Richard(R)D\abc.bat""
```

Answer (score -2):

you missed out the ending quotes so the command will be like this

`CMD /C "C:\Users\Richard(R)D\abc.bat"`

Hope this will help u fix it.